# When exporting HTML 5 data change the thead [dataTables]

Tags: datatables

I would like to change the thead when exporting a pdf or cvs. The reason is because the content of the th in the thead are **images**. And when i do export (because are images), then ***the content is empty***.

There is a way to change the content only when i export ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution!! I share it, because might be useful for someone else.

What i did is put the text and the image in the th, and then style and hidde the text. You don't see it in the webpage but when you print it you can see it.

html

```
 <th title="Castells"><img src='image.png' ><h3 class="hideText">Castells</h3></th>
```

css

```
.hideText{
  text-indent: -9999px;
  font-size: 1px;
}
```